# Get value after a specified word

Tags: php

I have a function with a parameter to pass.

For example:

```
$this->avatar->getAvatar('size=s/user=Synergy');
```

Now I want to explode the string at "/" and get the key for example "user" and the value "Synergy". And this for every explode.

Here is my function:

```
public function getAvatar($params)
  {
    $this->params = explode('/', $params);

    if(strpos($this->params, 'size=') !== false) {
      $this->size = // how to get value after "=" ??
    }

    if(strpos($this->params, 'user=') !== false) {
      $this->user = // how to get value after "=" ??
    }
  }
```

Comment: use `substr` http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: do you can give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<?php

$var = 'size=s3435/user=Synergy';
$temp = explode('/', $var);
//Fetch size
$pos = strpos($temp[0], '=');
echo substr($temp[0], 0, $pos); //key
echo substr($temp[0], $pos+1);  //value

//Fetch user
$pos = strpos($temp[1], '=');
echo substr($temp[1], 0, $pos);
echo substr($temp[1], $pos+1);
?>
```

Avail @ https://ideone.com/BxqooK

*Note: Use loop if you have many key-value pairs separated by `/`*

Comment: Thats good but is it possible to do this in a foreach loop because i have a lot of params to give and for every single to do this is not so good.

Comment: $temp is array, so use `foreach`

Comment: okay but i also need the word before the "=" it only return the value after the "="

Comment: Updated the answer. As mentioned in the commnet under question, look at the  `substr` http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php  for self-learning.

Comment: Thanks, working, im new to php so i need more help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode()`

```
$var = 'size=s/user=Synergy';
$temp = explode('user=', $var);
$username = ! empty($temp[1]) ? $temp[1] : '';
```

Comment: Then i need to do it for every param? for example i have size=s and direction=3, then i need to do: $temp = explode('size=', $var);  and $temp = explode('direction=', $var);

Comment: You will be end up in generating many 2-sized array, if you have many key-value pairs .

Answer (score 0):

if you replace `/` by `&` and parse the string with the php method `parse_str` :

```
$infos = array();
parse_str(str_replace('/', '&', $params), $infos);
```

$infos now looks like:

```
array(2) {
  ["size"]=>  string(1) "s"
  ["user"]=> string(4) "Synergy"
}
```

Finish by :

```
$this->size = $infos['size'];
$this->user = $infos['user'];
```